# Permission denied on exec() from a binary running as root

Tags: android, process, permissions, exec, root

I have a C binary that I run using root user (su -c binary_path) in Android.

Everything works fine until the binary tries to exec*() another binary. It actually works on most devices, however on some I get EACCES error.

The C binary is actually started using this:

```
execlp("su","su","-c",binary_path,NULL);
```

At some point, the binary will try to make those calls (simplified):

```
fork();

...

// child here

execlp("sh","sh","-c",script,NULL);
```

Actually tested on different Android 6.0 devices, a Nexus 9 and a S7. Nexus 9 ok, S7 fails.

So I checked all permissions and security context of the following, found no difference:

```
/system/bin
/system/bin/sh
/system/bin/ls
<library_path>
/su/bin/su
```

Also checked the binary was running with UID/GID = 0, true on both devices.

In logcat, I don't see any audit for a missing permission or secure policy violation.

**EDIT**: Just verified the security context the binary is running under:

```
$ps -Z
u:r:init:s0          root ...
```

Same for both devices whether exec() works or not.

**EDIT2**: On the device it fails, /proc/kmsg contains this when trying to exec():

```
Restricted making process. PID = 8868(<binary>) PPID = 8340(<binary>)
```

No avc from selinux, and this text cannot be found in AOSP source code.

Comment: use you a java application to run C code?

Comment: The binary is started from a shared library called from a Java app. Just to clarify again, the binary is granted root just fine, and may call exec() which will fail on some devices, not all.

Comment: Maybe it's explicit permission on Manifest? try to add  WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: The app already has this permission. The binary file is located under /data/local with all permission set as required, also tried with 777, made no difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After searching for "Restricted making process" on Google, I stumbled across Samsung kernels for the S5 and S6 (not the S7).

```
if(CHECK_ROOT_UID(current))
    if(sec_restrict_fork())
    {
        PRINT_LOG("Restricted making process. PID = %d(%s) "
                        "PPID = %d(%s)\n",
            current->pid, current->comm,
            current->parent->pid, current->parent->comm);
        return -EACCES;
    }
```

And the sec_restrict_fork() contains this:

```
if (sec_check_execpath(current->mm, "/data/")) {
    ret = 1;
    goto out;
}
```

Hence the failure on Samsung devices and no others.

Comment: Bless you for sharing this!

Comment: As far as I can see, this issue also impacts some non-Samsung devices as of now, e.g. Nexus 5.